# What will I input in the interaction window with this program i search? sorry beginner

Tags: scheme

I don't know how to edit here in stack sorry for this.. But I want to learn what should I
input in interaction window of scheme .. TY

```
#lang scheme
(define sort #f)
(define merge #f)
(let ()
  (define dosort
    (lambda (pred? ls n)
      (if (= n 1)
          (list (car ls))
          (let ((i (quotient n 2)))
            (domerge pred?
                     (dosort pred? ls i)
                     (dosort pred? (list-tail ls i) (- n i)))))))
  (define domerge
    (lambda (pred? l1 l2)
      (cond
        ((null? l1) l2)
        ((null? l2) l1)
        ((pred? (car l2) (car l1))
         (cons (car l2) (domerge pred? l1 (cdr l2))))
        (else (cons (car l1) (domerge pred? (cdr l1) l2))))))
  (set! sort
    (lambda (pred? l)
      (if (null? l) l (dosort pred? l (length l)))))
  (set! merge
    (lambda (pred? l1 l2)
      (domerge pred? l1 l2))))
```

Comment: What should you input for what?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There are two windows in DrRacket. The definition window and the interaction window..This is what I search and copy it in definition window . when I compile it I need to type something in INTERACTION WINDOW to see what can i run from it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is a sorting procedure. With a very strange way of definition. In the interactions area, just enter

```
(sort < '(6 5 2 1))
'(1 2 4 6)
```

for example. You need to provide a function that compares 2 items of the list. Another example:

```
 (sort string>? '("c" "b" "a" "d"))
 ("d" "c" "b" "a")
```